# remove special character [ ] in array java

Tags: java, arrays

In my program I have the following string of Array, when I process the program the output have the square bracket [], but I need without the square bracket []. any suggestion in how to remove them?

```
private final static String[] l0 = {"az","Fh md Br", "Inr Gt Cn", "Bl Gs he St st", "Mae is a nw Get", "Pam is a Ml rm", "Comr lab Pl Mt hs", "za"};

public static String sfuffle()
{
List<String> shuffled = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(phraseString));
    Collections.shuffle( shuffled );
    System.out.println(shuffled);// added only to have the output
    return  shuffled + "\n";    
}
```

output:

```
[az, Mae is a nw Get, Bl Gs he St st, Fh md Br, za, Comr lab Pl Mt hs, Inr Gt Cn, Pam is a Ml rm]
```

my desired output would be:

```
az, Mae is a nw Get, Bl Gs he St st, Fh md Br, za, Comr lab Pl Mt hs, Inr Gt Cn, Pam is a Ml rm
```

Comment: what do you mean by outout? what you see on your console? the return value? or both?

Comment: @PhilippSander obviously the returned value - the System.out is there only for debug.

Comment: @MightyPork and why are oyu sure sure that he doesn't want both?

Comment: I'm assuming that from the comment: `// added only to have the output`

Comment: @MightyPork so: the op sees the console outout as output not the return value as you are asuming

Comment: I think we should not blindly follow his comment and observations - the goal is clearly to get it as a return value.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
String str = shuffled.toString();
return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + "\n";
```

---

By popular demand, I'll add an explanation of why you're getting a string with brackets in the first place. When you write something like

```
shuffled + "\n"
```

this is converted to

```
new StringBuilder().append(shuffled).append("\n")
```

[`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a class designed for string concatenation and manipulation. When you append an object (`shuffled`, in this case), the string returned by the object's `toString()` method is appended. Now, shuffled is an `ArrayList`, and uses the `toString()` method defined in `AbstractCollection`. You can see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) that `toString()` will return a string of the form `[e1, e2, ..., en]` (where each `ei` is an element of the collection). Of course, `"\n"` is a newline and will not be directly visible.

Comment: This solves this one case, but does not explain what's happening, or how to do it better.

Comment: @MightyPork The OP didn't ask what's happening, and a downvote here seems excessive. I don't know what you mean by "how to do it better", I can't think of a simpler approach than this.

Comment: +1 for a surprisingly simple answer, although a quick explanation about the toString method wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: @MightyPork I added some explanation.

Comment: String str = shuffled.toString();
return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + "\n";
thanks arshajii
thats have solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
return  shuffled + "\n";
```

You are in fact doing this:

```
return  shuffled.toString() + "\n";
```

The brackets come from `ArrayList`'s implementation of `toString()`.

---

With a `for` loop, you can build the string your way, without depending on the `toString()` implementation:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < shuffled.size(); i++) {
    if(i > 0) s += ", "; // add the separator
    s += shuffled.get(i); // add list item
}
return s + "\n";
```

Comment: What you are in fact doing is `new StringBuilder().append(shuffled).append("\n").toString()`. Also, why would you go through the trouble of creating the string yourself from scratch? You can simply manipulate the string returned by `toString()`.

Comment: @arshajii It is not a good practice to rely on something like that, the implementation may change (although it's unlikely). And really no need to complicate the matter with StringBuilder, it will be used by the compiler in either case, so why to obfuscate the source.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets come from ArrayList's implementation of `toString()` 
(just like MightyPork said)

Simply remove the first and last character of a String with

`return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + "\n";`

So you method will look like this:

```
public static String sfuffle()
{
    List<String> shuffled = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(phraseString));
    Collections.shuffle( shuffled );
    String str = shuffled.toString();
    str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1); //this line removes the brackets
    System.out.println(str); //for debugging
    return  str + "\n";    
}
```

It will print the list without brackets and will return it without brackets

Comment: Really no need to post answer if there are already multiple with exactly the same solution.

Comment: this answer is just my way to explain and solve it... i really don't get the downvote

Comment: @PhilippSander I find it interesting how the first sentence is exactly the same as in my answer. Just saying.

Comment: @MightyPork i honored you :)